# getting b'no arguments in initialization list' from ox.projection.project_gdf(city,yerevan.crs)

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to get map of country I am working on but get getting `b'no arguments in initialization list'` as error. Code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import osmnx as ox
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon,  MultiPolygon
import os
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] = "C:\\Users\\torre\\Desktop\\Yerevan shapefile\\Yerevan.shp"

import pyproj as project


#Load Yerevan city from openstreetmap using osmnx api

city = ox.gdf_from_place("Yerevan, Armenia",which_result=2)
print(city.crs)
meta = ox.projection.project_gdf(city,yerevan.crs)
#get error of b'no arguments in initialization list' fig, ax = ox.plot_shape(city)
print(city.crs)
```

Comment: Hi Todd, welcome to SO. Which line raises the error? An [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might help us helping you out.

Comment: Why are you setting the PROJ_LIB environment variable to the path to a shapefile?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a reproducible code snippet, so it's a bit unclear what you're trying to do here. But the following reproducible code snippet for downloading/projecting Yerevan works fine in the current release (v0.15.1) of OSMnx:

```py
import osmnx as ox
city = ox.geocode_to_gdf('Yerevan, Armenia', which_result=2)
print(city.crs) # prints epsg:4326
city_proj = ox.project_gdf(city, to_crs='epsg:2935')
print(city_proj.crs) # prints epsg:2935
```